# What does the following deployment strategy imply in kubernetes?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using default deployment strategy for my load-balancer service in kubernetes, and when I describe my deployment the strategy looks like follows:

```
Replicas:               2 desired | 2 updated | 2 total | 2 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
```

MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  1 max unavailable, 1 max surge

So according to the description, there should not be any downtime. However, there's still a downtime in the service. 
How can I make sure there's zero downtime?

Comment: Since you have MinReadySeconds: 0, after the  new instance of the pod has been started the old one gets immediately killed. I suggest raising MinReadySeconds to a fair amount of seconds (30 maybe) and ensure that you have the LivenessProbe configured for your pod. That could help.

Comment: So, if I were to make MinReadySeconds 30, what's the recommended period for liveness and readiness probe? Also, do you think making max unavailable to 0 will make be good for ensuring zero downtime?

Comment: I don't know if there is any recommendation about the liveness probe interval. Max unavailable 0 would be helpful in your needs only of your deployment has the number of replicas = 1

Comment: I have 2 replicas, so i guess I'd not touch maxunavailabe field for now.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you are using the `as fast as possible` approach of [`Rolling Updates`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/).

While this is a good approach it's better to use `Replicas: 3`, because you might end up with 2 `pods` down during update.

You should implement [`ReadinessProbe`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes) that might look like the following:

```
readinessProbe:  
  httpGet:  
     path: /  
     port: 8080  
     initialDelaySeconds: 5  
     periodSeconds: 5  
     successThreshold: 1
```

- `initialDelaySeconds`: Number of seconds after the container has started before readiness probes are initiated.
- `periodSeconds`: How often to perform the probe. Default to 10 seconds.
- `successThreshold`: Minimum consecutive successes for the probe to be considered successful after having failed. Defaults to 1.

I also recommend reading [Enable Rolling updates in Kubernetes with Zero downtime](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/enable-rolling-updates-in-kubernetes-with-zero-downtime-31d7ec388c81), as they nicely explains the use of Rolling updates.

Comment: I have readiness and liveness, both, probes enabled. I think downtime is pretty random. Few days ago, right after I made the deployment, I wasnt able to access the service endpoints for a good 10-12 seconds. However, when I was testing the same thing today, there was no downtime at all! And I have not changed anything in deployment.yaml.

Comment: Well that is possible, what you can do is to check which `pod` are you trying to connect to. Is it a new updated once or old removed one.

Comment: As whites11 pointed out, and to add to this answer, using changing MinReadySeconds from 0 to something like 30 will mean that the next pod to be replaced will wait 30 seconds. Ideally, the MinReadySeconds should be equal or higher than the amount of time your pod needs to startup